# Shrink a table to fit columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This seems like a pretty basic fix, but I couldn't find anything. I want to be able to shrink a table so it fits its contents. In the picture below the table extends beyond its columns.

Here's what I have:
[image]

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: #f4f0ea;
  margin: 20px;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background: #ababab;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id='sample1'>
  <caption>Sample table 1</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `table extends beyond its columns`... I don't understand what you mean here? You want to make the table smaller?

Comment: The background behind the table looks like the table is inside another element? The table seems ok to me, otherwise.

Comment: Yes, do you see how the background color extends across the page? I want to be able to end it where the last column is. The background color of the body tag is white. The parent element of the table is the body.

Comment: @user13764177 in your example you can see the background ends with the table. So we can't help you here. I suspect you applied some css to the background of the parent of the table.